# Symfony 4 service alias

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have service in bundle

@sonata.page.twig.extension

it is private.

I need set is as public.

Try  1.

```
  Sonata\PageBundle\Twig\Extension\PageExtension:
    alias: "@sonata.page.twig.extension"
    public: true
```

get

```
 InvalidArgumentException
Unable to replace alias "Sonata\PageBundle\Twig\Extension\PageExtension" with actual definition "@sonata.page.twig.extension".
```

Try 2

```
mea.sonata.page.twig.extension:
    alias: "@sonata.page.twig.extension"
    public: true
```

same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To clarify the use of '@' in this example : "@sonata.page.twig.extension"

Without it, you are telling the container to pass the string **sonata.page.twig.extension**.
With it, you are telling the container to pass the service **sonata.page.twig.extension**.

From the documentation, see the following comment in the code : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

```
 # explicitly configure the service
    App\Service\MessageGenerator:
        arguments:
            # the '@' symbol is important: that's what tells the container
            # you want to pass the *service* whose id is 'monolog.logger.request',
            # and not just the *string* 'monolog.logger.request'
            $logger: '@monolog.logger.request'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK found solution

```
  Sonata\PageBundle\Twig\Extension\PageExtension:
    alias: 'sonata.page.twig.extension'
    public: true
```

Why sometimes @sonata.page.twig.extension sometimes sonata.page.twig.extension

Comment: An alias is always a service.  Hence no need for an @ symbol. It is a bit confusing and it catches me all the time as well.  They could have made it work with or without an @ but hey, it wakes you up at least.